# How to connect to Netezza database from Python?

Tags: python, database, netezza

Using python, how to connect to netezza database.

Since PIP install is not working in my corporate network. I can't import pyodbc and jaydebeapi. Please suggest is there any way to connect netezza database and fetch data from table.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install nzpy https://pypi.org/project/nzpy/
2. Install pandas https://pypi.org/project/pandas/
3. Use connection to Netezza to fill pandas' `DataFrame` using `read_sql` function

   ```
   import nzpy
   import pandas as pd

   conn = nzpy.connect(user="admin", password="password", host='localhost', port=5480, database="db1", securityLevel=1, logLevel=0)
   df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM some_table', conn)
   ```

Voila.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your hands are basically tied. If you don't have the means to "speak" to the database (JDBC/ODBC) then there's really nothing you can do.

Perhaps you could elaborate as to why your `pip` application isn't working and try to get that solved?